# Date within date range with JavaScript and Moment.js not evaluating correctly

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I apologize in advance if this seem like a stupid question, but I have never used Moment.js before.

I have the following method (code inherited from previous developer), and cannot understand why the evaluation does not work. I am sure it is something trivial.

**Note:** only the dates `>= weekOne` in the `if` statement evaluates the correct dates. The other `else if` clauses does not evaluate even when the dates match.

```
var myObject = $scope.uptimeData;
var uptimeTotal = [];
if (myObject) {
    var weekOne = moment().subtract(7, "days").format("YYYY-MM-DD");
    var weekTwo = moment().subtract(14, "days").format("YYYY-MM-DD");
    var weekThree = moment().subtract(21, "days").format("YYYY-MM-DD");
    var weekFour = moment().subtract(28, "days").format("YYYY-MM-DD");
    var weekFive = moment().subtract(35, "days").format("YYYY-MM-DD");
    var weekSix = moment().subtract(42, "days").format("YYYY-MM-DD");
    var weekSeven = moment().subtract(49, "days").format("YYYY-MM-DD");

    var weekOneTotalSuccess = 0;
    var weekTwoTotalSuccess = 0;
    var weekThreeTotalSuccess = 0;
    var weekFourTotalSuccess = 0;
    var weekFiveTotalSuccess = 0;
    var weekSixTotalSuccess = 0;
    var weekOneTotalFail = 0;
    var weekTwoTotalFail = 0;
    var weekThreeTotalFail = 0;
    var weekFourTotalFail = 0;
    var weekFiveTotalFail = 0;
    var weekSixTotalFail = 0;
    Object.keys(myObject).map(function (key, index) {
        if (myObject[key].successes) {
            if (key >= weekOne) {
                weekOneTotalSuccess = weekOneTotalSuccess + myObject[key].successes;
            } else if (key >= weekTwo && key < weekThree) {
                weekTwoTotalSuccess = weekTwoTotalSuccess + myObject[key].successes;
            } else if (key >= weekThree && key < weekFour) {
                weekThreeTotalSuccess = weekThreeTotalSuccess + myObject[key].successes;
            } else if (key >= weekFour && key < weekFive) {
                weekFourTotalSuccess = weekFourTotalSuccess + myObject[key].successes;
            } else if (key >= weekFive && key < weekSix) {
                weekFiveTotalSuccess = weekFiveTotalSuccess + myObject[key].successes;
            } else if (key >= weekSix && key < weekSeven) {
                weekSixTotalSuccess = weekSixTotalSuccess + myObject[key].successes;
            }
            else {

            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Here is a sample of the data:**

```
"2017-05-03": {
  "failures": 816, 
  "successes": 18378
}, 
"2017-05-04": {
  "failures": 1067, 
  "successes": 22302
}, 
"2017-05-05": {
  "failures": 1008, 
  "successes": 82599
}, 
"2017-05-07": {
  "failures": 2724, 
  "successes": 142854
}, 
"2017-05-08": {
  "failures": 1329, 
  "successes": 149028
}
```

Comment: Please. Provide this code as a Code Snippet or Hosted on JsFiddle

Comment: @LouisLecocq not sure how to add as a snippet as it has linked libraries such as AngularJs and Moment.js.

Comment: I suggest to use `isBefore`, `isAfter` and `isBetween` (See [Query](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/) section of the docs) for comparing moment objects instead of comparing formatted string representation with `>` and `>` (even if I think you'll get the right order if you use `YYYY-MM-DD` format). What is the issue with your code? Which is the issue with the _evaluation_?

Comment: @VincenzoC it simply does not enter the clause when it matches. I believe you must be right. It must be the string date and not string object issue.

Comment: @onmyway please not that even using `isBetween` in your code for your data sample you will have `weekOneTotalSuccess = weekTwoTotalSuccess = ... = weekSixTotalSuccess = 0` (because all dates in the input samples are older then 6 weeks ago). Let me know if you solved your issue anyway.

Comment: Good point @VincenzoC. Careful with your data sample ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Issue**

You are comparing two Strings.
For instance, on your first iteration, your value are as :

```
key => "2017-05-03"
weekOne => moment().subtract(7, "days").format("YYYY-MM-DD"); /* which returns a formatted string */
```

The `>` and `<` operator are not really destined to be used with String Type variable.

> Note : Each of these operators will call the valueOf() function on each operand before a comparison is made.

**Answer**

As long as you are using Moment.js, you should refer to [the MomentJS Query documentation section](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/) in order to compare if a date is prior or posterior to another date.

Comment: Thank you for your response! Would I replace my if clauses for if clauses such as `if (moment(key).isBetween(weekTwo, weekThree) {
 weekTwoTotalSuccess = weekTwoTotalSuccess + myObject[key].successes;
}`

Comment: That should work according to the documentation.
Please accept the answer if your problem is solved ;)

Comment: Thank you, it works great. And I have learned some Moment.js in the process :)